# Does Windows/Linux running from USB leave traces on internal disks?

Tags: linux, windows, liveusb

I am a person that is constantly on the move. Therefore, I usually carry USB sticks with operating systems that I can easily run without leaving any trace on the host system. Usually, I just run Linux from these USBs, which is great because the data is not persistent and is wiped as soon as you turn the computer off.

However, I have tried to replicate the same thing with Windows. But, the live windows session is persisting after a reboot. All the data from the previous session doesn't get wiped like it usually does with Linux.

This has got me thinking. Where exactly is the data for this session being stored? Is it being stored on the USB stick? Or is it being stored somewhere on the HDD/SSD and can be potentially recovered by a person/entity tech savvy enough?

Likewise for Linux. Although the data is wiped after a reboot, is it completely wiped? Could the data be getting stored somewhere on the HDD/SSD?

Answer (score 1):

"[Windows To Go](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview)", as Microsoft calls it, uses the storage it is running from (flashdrive in your case) as a mostly-normal writable boot volume. Stuff that gets written every boot, like updating logs, will be written to the flashdrive. Stuff that the user changes, like creating a file in their Documents directory, will be written to the flashdrive. Stuff that changes the system, like Windows Updates, will be written to the flashdrive. You get the picture.

By default W2G does not mount or even scan internal disks installed in whatever machine it runs on. You can choose to "online" these disks and mount their volumes, but it won't happen automatically. It may also be possible to mount the volumes read-only without leaving any trace (at least, any trace detectable from conventional software running on the same machine later) but I'm less sure about that (the usual way to mount a volume totally read-only in Windows actually modifies the volume metadata; this can be detected by later tools that read the partition metadata).

If you want a version of Windows that does not persist any changes, this might be possible with "full" Windows (and no third-party software), but the obvious solution is [Windows PE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro) (WinPE), the Windows Pre-installation Environment. WinPE is designed to run from read-only media (like CDs and DVDs), although it can run from flashdrives or similar as well (and these days usually does, since optical drives are becoming rare). Its most common uses are to install or repair Windows, but it can be used for various other tasks including running graphical or command-line Win32 programs with networking and so on. It uses a RAM disk for its temporary file system, just like a Linux live image.

However, WinPE has some significant limitations that make it unsuitable as a general-purpose live install. It is not self-updating, does not have most of the convenience and backward-compatibility Windows features common on full Windows, and is subject to a 72-hour limit for continuous operation. You could, before the end of that period, write files you want to keep to some writable storage (either the same flashdrive you're running WinPE from, another external drive, or internal storage) so you don't lose everything when the timer runs out, but this is definitely... awkward. Additionally, since WinPE is designed with the express intention of using it to modify the internal drives of the computer it's running on (to install or repair Windows), I don't know if it's possible to make it leave internal drives offline by default the way W2G does.

There are potentially other options, especially now that W2G is discontinued and no longer being updated. You might be able to use the tools talked about here: https://www.howtogeek.com/406118/how-and-why-to-run-portable-versions-of-windows/, or simply search for "portable Windows 10" and see what comes up. I don't know what, if any, special behaviors around internal disks to expect from the output of such tools, though.